# Streaming data from Twitter to HDFS command not working

Tags: hdfs, flume

I will like to stream data from tweeter to hdfs, i used this command: ./bin/flume-ng agent -n TwitterAgent -c conf -f /usr/lib/apache-flume-1.4.0-bin/conf/flume.conf

I can't get the result i am expecting. No data streamed.

Anyone who has a linus command for streaming data from tweeter to hdfs?

Answer (score 0):

First of all go to apache-flume-1.4.0-bin directory from your terminal

**1]** **cd apache-flume-1.4.0-bin**

Then write the below command on terminal

**2]** **bin/flume-ng agent --conf ./conf/ -f conf/flume.conf -Dflume.root.logger=DEBUG,console -n TwitterAgent**